# Integral of a small function

Tags: calculus, integration

How might I go about calculating $$\int_\pi^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x\log x}\text{d}x$$

I honestly don't know where to start.

Comment: @Panphobia Good observation! I seem to have written the question wrong. I will edit

Comment: Have you tried Integration by Parts?

Comment: @Panphobia Yes, though using that seemed to make the function much worse.

Comment: Take $x=e^{u}$. Then the improper integral takes the form $\int_{\log(\pi)}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(e^{u})}{u}du$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see how that helps @Albert.

Comment: Yah, but your integral is nonelementary.

Comment: Almost surely your integral does not have a simple closed form, better forget about it.

Comment: Are you sure you really need to compute such integral, or is it enough to prove it is convergent (by Dirichlet's test, for instance)?

Comment: I am interested in computing it. The reason for having to compute it is because if there is a closed form to this one, then I will be almost there to solving a closed form for the one I just posted

Comment: what does Wolfram Alpha say?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Nothing.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+pi+to+infinity+of+%28sin+x%29%2F%28x+ln+x%29